Why does Mathematica produce a complex solution to ODE?
$Assumptions = {r>0, σ>0,x>=0};
Assuming[Assumptions,
  FullSimplify@DSolve[-1*r*V[x] + µ*x*V'[x]+σ^2*(1/2)*x^2*V''[x] + c*x == 0,
   V[x],x] ]

The output is
{{V[x] -> (c*x)/(r - µ) + x^((σ^2 - I*σ*Sqrt[-8*r - (σ^2 - 2*µ)^2/σ^2] - 2*µ)/
  (2*σ^2))*(C[1] + x^((I*Sqrt[-8*r - (σ^2 - 2*µ)^2/σ^2])/σ)*C[2])}}

I don't why the I part is produced. I tried in Maple without using any assumptions and the output (in latex) doesn't contain the I part:
$$
F\! \left(x\right)=x^{\frac{\sigma^{2}-2 \mu +\sqrt{\sigma^{4}-4 \mu  \,\sigma^{2}+8 r \sigma^{2}+4 \mu^{2}}}{2 \sigma^{2}}} c_{2}+x^{-\frac{-\sigma^{2}+\sqrt{\sigma^{4}-4 \mu  \,\sigma^{2}+8 r \sigma^{2}+4 \mu^{2}}+2 \mu}{2 \sigma^{2}}} c_{1}+\frac{x c}{-\mu +r}
$$
I have checked the following discussion and tried the suggestions, but it doesn't work.

I actually don't see how this question is different than the last one. It's exactly the same issue (Mathematica treats variables as complex by default, functions like Sqrt and Sin can be complex even if the parameters are real, depending on their relationships, and Mathematica simplifies things according to its own rules, etc.). What is actually the issue with the expression? Do you just want to pull those Is back in the square roots? Then do Expand[expr /. Sqrt[a_] :> -I Sqrt[-a]] /. x^a_ :> x^Simplify@a, where expr is the output of your code.

The solution is correct, as it verifies the ode. some cas can produce solution with complex I in it, but this can be simplified out (depending on the solution of course) by algebraic manipulations.  Here is example.  https://i.sstatic.net/mLR4GmsD.png  you see, same solution. One has complex in it, and one form does not.  code: ode=y''[x]/y[x]+m^2==0; sol=DSolveValue[ode,y[x],x]; sol=TrigToExp[sol]//Simplify

Declare all variables PositiveReals and look for the most simplified expression in that  special case. The general solution can be derived from the discriminants occurring in the root expressions.
  Assuming[r > 0 && \[Sigma] > 0 & x >= 0 && \[Mu] > 0 && c > 0, 
  PowerExpand@FullSimplify@
  DSolve[-1*r*V[x] + µ*x*V'[x] + \[Sigma]^2*(1/2)*x^2*V''[x] + c*x ==
  0, V[x], x]]

$$V(x)\to \frac{c x}{r-\mu }+x^{-\frac{\sqrt{8 r \sigma ^2+\left(\sigma ^2-2 \mu \right)^2}}{2 \sigma ^2}-\frac{\mu }{\sigma ^2}+\frac{1}{2}} \left(\frac{c_2 \sigma ^2 x^{\frac{\sqrt{8 r \sigma ^2+\left(\sigma ^2-2 \mu \right)^2}}{\sigma ^2}}}{\sqrt{8 r \sigma ^2+\left(\sigma ^2-2 \mu \right)^2}}+c_1\right)$$
